# How do I analyze 17 different gases from a sample?

Tags: chromatography

I am designing a test setup in which I heat a battery until it releases its gases, and I need to analyze the composition of the fumes. Below is the list of gases that are believed to be present in the battery's fumes. I was planning on just using a bunch of gas detection tubes, but they don't seem to be available for all these gases. I was thinking about moving on to buying a gas chromatograph instead since, so far, it seems cheaper than getting a bunch of tests, but I have never used a GC, so I don't know if this would even work for so many gases.

If I were to go the GC route, what would I need to learn and buy in order to test for these gases? Is there a handbook that demonstrates the proper setups for different gases since I think you need to change some physical components for proper testing of different gases (I didn't find any)? Or is there a better method to test for this?

[image]

Comment: Well, this should be easy for GC-MS, but unless you'd use the hardware for many years, you should "outsource" the tests.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought too. My boss wanted me to figure out if it's possible for us to do the GC-MS ourselves so he can sell this service himself. I work at an aerospace flammability testing lab, so we burn lots of stuff, and we could get more business if we also offer to analyze the gases off other samples we burn up.

Comment: GC without MS is sufficient to recognize the presence of the mentioned gases. GC-MS is better. But GC alone is sufficient, if you have samples of the pure gases to determine their retention times.

Comment: I think I would have highly pure gases since I am planning on conducting this test in a vacuum chamber. Would GC be enough to tell me the composition of the gas, ie 20% of one thing, 10% of another, etc? That is the purpose of the spike heights in the data, right?

Comment: I read a bit more about the differences between GC and GCMS. I have a lot of molecules that only vary by an atom; would this make it too difficult for the GC by itself to analyze the gas composition? Or since the molecules are simple and the variation in weight is a large percentage of the total weight, the GC doesn't struggle with finding the difference between CO and CO2 or C3H6O3 and C4H6O3?

Comment: GC can sometimes distinguish deuterated vs. non. deuterated compound. Your analysis must be a *very simple exercise* for GC people. The key question is choosing the right column.

Comment: Sounds good. Where can I find sources on choosing the right column and sampling techniques and all other things that would be important with using the equipment properly?

Comment: This is, I´m sure, a solution you can buy, with all equipment and a manual. Don´t reinvent a wheel unless you already know very well what you are doing.

Comment: @AlbertGarcia, Search the literature. Use Google Scholar. Also contact Supelco and other GC column manufacturers. They will tell you the right column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a permanent gas analyzer that has an FID channel for hydrocarbons and CO2, with a TCD detector for H2 and HF and a third MS channel if needed. Basically, this would mean you split your sample into three different columns in the oven to analyze them for different things. I agree with Karl and don't reinvent the wheel. I've done the hydrocarbons (C1-12) and CO2 and permanent gases using a Thermo Trace 1310 with an FID and TCD detector and would recommend that for ease of use. Then I would probably add an MS detector to it in case you need it.

How are you hoping to get the battery gases into the GC? I think you could fit a battery into a headspace vial and heat it up to release the gases then directly inject the headspace into the GC.